# Bitnami nginx install memcached make command error

Tags: nginx, makefile, bitnami

I follow this link https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/#how-to-install-the-memcached-module-using-the-libmemcached-library to install memcached in bitnami nginx stack of the Google platform centos 7.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar -zxf libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-1.0.18
./configure --prefix=/home/lnmp/common
make
```

`/home/lnmp` is my bitnami install path

when I run `make` command , it will show error log below

```
make -j2  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/lnmp/libmemcached-1.0.18'
  CXXLD    libhashkit/libhashkit.la
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-crc32.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-digest.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-function.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-has.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-hashkit.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_Z21hashkit_one_at_a_timePKcmPv' can not be used when making a shared object
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-jenkins.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-md5.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-murmur3.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-rijndael.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-str_algorithm.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-strerror.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: libhashkit/.libs/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `calloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libhashkit/libhashkit.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lnmp/libmemcached-1.0.18'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

You can download the Makefile to help me modify this file in this link [libmemcached Makefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHGCQaNviiQmT1krFfVTWBhJKKgm7tMk/view?usp=sharing)

And someone said `relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata can not be used when making a shared object` error is because building static library need -fPIC option, need add `CFLAGS += -fPIC` to fix it.But This Makefile is too complex, I don't know how to add it and how to fix it,anyone can help me?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. The ngx_stream_core_module module is available since version 1.9.0 but it is not built by default. Unfortunately we do not use that option when building the component and that's why you can't enable it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Jota Martos I still don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi again, as I mentioned that module is not included in the Bitnami solution so you can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

In configure file,

Find following line:

```
for flag in -fPIE -pie; do
```

replace it by

```
for flag in -fPIC -pic; do
```

./configure and make again